# been trying to find this font desperately. (I've underlined the letters from it), if you know which one it is, that'd be awesome!

Tags: fonts

[image]

any ideas? or resembling ones? (I've underlined the letters from it so you see exactly) ♡

Comment: I usually when I try to identify a font I get significant results. This one however I couldn't, nothing similar showed up. I don't think you can find it but there are prettier alternatives IMO

Comment: hey cristobal!! thank you so very much for the insight!! i do try as much as well too with the automatic ones but they didn't manage for this pic, that's why!! eheh. and if you have any names for those alternatives, lmk! ☻ best, raf

Answer (score 2):

There are so many scripts these days it's hard to find the exact one, but the design is a light or "casual" script. Just searching from House Industries' library, I see [SignPainter Casual](https://houseind.com/hi/signpainter) and [Plinc Milo](https://houseind.com/hi/plinc-milo#) as being in the same space. [Laura Worthington](https://lauraworthingtondesign.com/fonts/?category=script) also has many great script fonts in the same space. SignPainter is free with a Mac, if you have one.

Comment: hey copilot!! tysm for your answer, it's literally the best. merci infiniment!!

Answer (score 1):

I worked with embroidery softwares and some of them have their own fonts , this might be one of them.